# Deselecting ListBox item in code without firing event

Tags: c#

I have four ListBox items on my C# form. What I want is for only one item to be selected at any one time. That is to say, one item on any of the four ListBox controls.

I know that you can change the SelectedIndex to -1 which deselects the currently selected item, and that's great. The problem is the event firing.

So my four ListBox controls are A, B, C and D. I have a SelectedIndexChanged event on A which sets the SelectedIndex of B, C and D to -1. I also have such an event on B which sets the SelectedIndex of A, C and D to -1, and so on for all four.

I select an item on A, which calls the SelectedIndex for B, C and D to become -1. But then that calls their SelectedIndexChanged event, which sets all the others (including A) to -1 too. If I could stop them calling that event for this short time, that would be great.

I hope someone can offer some assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just have one listbox with groups?

Answer (score 1):

Just use some temporary boolean variable on your events... something like:

```
bool _AChangingB = false;

void ListboxA_selectedIndexChangedDelegate(/* event parameters */)
{
  _AChangingB = true;
  ListboxB.SelectedIndex = -1;
  _AChangingB = false;
}

void ListboxB_selectedIndexChangedDelegate(/* event parameters */)
{
  if(!_AChangingB) 
    ListboxA.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Something like this should work if your events are synchronous (if you are doing async then more care would be needed)

## Alternative

For your precise case, you could use the same function for all four listboxes and discriminate via the sender parameter:

```
bool _changing = false;

void Listboxes_selectedIndexChangedDelegate(object sender, /* blabla */)
{
  if(_changing) return;
  try
  {
    _changing = true;
    var allListBoxes = new ListBox[] { ListboxA, ListboxB, ListboxC, ListboxD };
    foreach(var listBox in allListBoxes)
      if(sender != listBox) 
        listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
  } 
  finally 
  {
    _changing = false;  
  }
}
```

Just giving ideas... it all depends on what events you actually require on your listboxes... hard to say with the info you gave

Comment: The "alternative" would be my choice in this case :)

Comment: You'd actually need to check if it's changing programmatically on the "alternative". I'm on my phone right now but will edit later. Guess it can be figured out from the first example

Comment: Edited adding prevention to process event again while in the original event